# Generated Request Medium?

Tags: http, security, postman

I got a doubt that is there any way to figure out at server end that by which medium the Http request is generated by client. Either it is Postman,
 Browser or an Android or IOS app.

And if there is a way can someone tell me how can I figure it out?

Maybe someone has already answered it but I couldn't found it please help

Comment: You can look at the `User-Agent`, unless the client lies about it.

Comment: on server when I analysed the request it shows user agent as  'okhttp/3.10.0' what can I say by seeing this?

Comment: Oh! Thanks, I just found the difference when request sent from android , browser and postman. it changes user agent

Comment: But can a client fake user-agent too?

Comment: The client controls everything about the request.  You can never trust the client.

Comment: Oh so how can I ensure that he cant modify or if he has modified it i get to know it?

Comment: You can't.  _You can never trust the client_.  A request is just bytes; any client can change any bytes he wants to.

Comment: Ok thanks man for helping